# Product recomendations - where is the line drawn between necessity and advertisement?

Tags: discussion

Are there any examples of a product recommendation that could be considered legitamate and not in violation with SE's framework?

Example:  Somebody needs to source electrical connectors for the wiring harness of the 1957 Dodge and only one place makes them that are exactly like the stock ones.

Comment: I don't know for sure about the SE network's rules... But in this particular field product recommendations seem somewhat necessary.

Comment: I feel the real problem here is that product recommendations don't appear to be explicitly discussed in the [Help Center](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I don't have the time right now do to it right, but if someone wants to review [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486/234810) and [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and post an appropriately worded suggestion, I'd certainly support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question should be asked without using a phrase like, "where can I get these electrical connectors?" and instead ask, "how can I connect X to Y?" This way the community can answer without such a narrow requirement.

It may be that there is a superior solution to the problem that has nothing to do with that exact part replacement, while not eliminating answers that may include possible suppliers of a stock replacement part.